# Select distinct ordered pair from table join

Tags: mysql, select

Please consider two tables with names. They are joined by Table A id, so that two names get associated.
Is there a MySQL query that returns distinct pair of names regardless the order?

First table:

```
table_a
+-----------+--------------+
|    id     |     name     |
+-----------+--------------+
|     1     |     John     |
+-----------+--------------+
|     2     |     Jane     |
+-----------+--------------+ 
|     3     |     Jane     |
+-----------+--------------+
|     4     |     Sammy    |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Second Table:

```
table_b
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
|    id     |     id_table_a    |    name     |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
|    1      |          1        |    Jane     |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
|    2      |          2        |    John     |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
|    3      |          3        |    Sammy    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
|    4      |          4        |    Tara     |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+
```

Desired result

```
(John, Jane)
(Jane, Sammy)  
(Sammy, Tara)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option using `least` and `greatest`:

```
select distinct least(a.name, b.name), greatest(a.name, b.name)
from table_a a 
  join table_b b on a.id = b.id_table_a
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c537d/1)

Comment: That's precisely it! One more question.. When I add more columns to the query the distinct stops working. For example: select distinct least(a.name, b.name), greatest(a.name, b.name), b.id_table_a
from table_a a 
  join table_b b on a.id = b.id_table_a
Is there a way of adding more columns without breaking the DISTINCT?

Comment: @random425 -- that's really a different question, you should probably ask a new one for that.  but the answer will depend on which id should be displayed since both would match... (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c537d/4)

Comment: Ok @sgeddes. Thks a lot!

Comment: New question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171187/select-distinct-ordered-pair-from-table-join-grouped-by-event-most-recent-date
Thks!