# Select distinct ordered pairs from table join grouped by event's most recent date

Tags: mysql, select, join, group-by

Following the post [Select distinct ordered pair from table join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39157850/select-distinct-ordered-pair-from-table-join)

How can I select the most recent John's joined rows grouped by ordered pair, regardless the order (e.g. John -> Jane or Jane -> John)?

First table:

```
table_a
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|    id     |     name     |     created_at    |
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|     1     |     John     |2016-08-26 15:40:21|
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|     2     |     Jane     |2016-08-26 15:37:21|
+-----------+--------------+ ------------------+
|     3     |     Jane     |2016-08-26 15:38:21|
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
|     4     |     Tara     |2016-08-26 15:39:21|
+-----------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Second Table:

```
table_b
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    id     |     id_table_a    |    name     |   message   |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1      |          1        |    Jane     |   Test 1    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    2      |          2        |    John     |   Test 2    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    3      |          3        |    Sammy    |   Test 3    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
|    4      |          4        |    John     |   Test 4    |
+-----------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

One possible result

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    id     |   name_a    |   name_b    |   message   |     created_at    |
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    1      |   John      |   Jane      |   Test 1    |2016-08-26 15:40:21|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+
|    4      |   Tara      |   John      |   Test 4    |2016-08-26 15:39:21|
+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/88af9)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(select a.id, a.name, b.name, b.message, a.created_at from a left join b on a.id=b.aid where a.name='John' order by a.created_at desc limit 1)
union all
(select a.id, a.name, b.name, b.message, a.created_at from a left join b on a.id=b.aid where b.name='John' order by a.created_at desc limit 1)
```

Comment: If I add one more message for John your code only shows 2 rows when it should show 3. Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b276c/1/0

Comment: why it should return 3 rows?
you wrote that you want most recent pairs, so one where John is in table a and one where John is in table b

Comment: The objective is to return every (most recent) John's association just once, i.e. (John, Jane), (John, Tara), (John, ...) regardless the table where the John row is. Thks anyway weedget :)

Answer (score 0):

This gets a bit messy.  Here's an option using `user-defined variables` to establish a `row_number` within each group of results and then filtering by row number = 1:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    @rn := if(@prev_name_a = name_a and @prev_name_b = name_b, @rn+1,
                if(@prev_name_a:=name_a,1,
                   if(@prev_name_b:=name_b, 1, 1)
                )
             ) rn
  from (
    select least(a.name, b.name) as name_a, 
        greatest(a.name, b.name) as name_b, 
        a.created_at,
        a.id, 
        b.message
    from table_a a 
      join table_b b on a.id = b.id_table_a
  ) t cross join (select @rn:=0, @prev_name_a:=null, @prev_name_b:=null) t1
  order by name_a, name_b, created_at desc
  ) t
where 'John' in (name_a, name_b) and rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f0c7/7)

Comment: If I add one more message with a repeating ordered pair like John -> Jane  your code returns an extra row with the repeating ordered pair. SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f0c7/1/0
Thks!

Comment: @random425 -- interesting, least and greatest are not being respected correctly with the user defined variables.  you can solve that by using another subquery though: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f0c7/7

Comment: I've changed the names to 9 digit long integers and the result is different. Any idea why? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3debfd/2